# readSeries, read and convert time-series data set?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data set in a csv file comprised as such

```
      ,Southern Europe,EasternE
2000M1,99.2714858,94.0655995,
2000M2,99.28204201,95.20956637,
2000M3,99.42063947,95.99514288,
2000M4,99.86433479,96.81388546,
2000M5,99.91074036,97.52828582,
2000M6,99.58204075,98.87835592,
2000M7,99.50302486,100.970238,
2000M8,99.79380714,101.0939461,
2000M9,100.1770355,102.5641483,
2000M10,100.4298271,103.8086486,
```

I'm attempting to read it into a ts object using readSeries such that the result is a
ts object with the time series as

```
Jan 2000 99.27148 .......
Feb 2000 99.28204 .......
Mar 2000 99.42063 .......
```

I'm trying to use POSIX but have no idea if it possible to get it to recognise this M1 M2 ... format, or if I have to do some clever conversion in the csv data file prior to reading it into the ts object?

Any suggestions most welcome.

Thanks

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** `readSeries` in the timeSeries package produces `"timesSeries"` class objects, not the `"ts"` class objects the questions asks for. To create a `"ts"` object try the following.  (By the way, the headings may be wrong in your data but I have just used them as is.  Fix them afterwards using `colnames`.)

```
Lines <- ",Southern Europe,EasternE
2000M1,99.2714858,94.0655995,
2000M2,99.28204201,95.20956637,
2000M3,99.42063947,95.99514288,
2000M4,99.86433479,96.81388546,
2000M5,99.91074036,97.52828582,
2000M6,99.58204075,98.87835592,
2000M7,99.50302486,100.970238,
2000M8,99.79380714,101.0939461,
2000M9,100.1770355,102.5641483,
2000M10,100.4298271,103.8086486,
"

# replace text=Lines with something like "myfile.csv"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, check.names = FALSE)
ts(DF, start = c(2000, 1), freq = 12)
```

which gives:

```
                   Southern Europe EasternE
Jan 2000  99.27149        94.06560       NA
Feb 2000  99.28204        95.20957       NA
Mar 2000  99.42064        95.99514       NA
Apr 2000  99.86433        96.81389       NA
May 2000  99.91074        97.52829       NA
Jun 2000  99.58204        98.87836       NA
Jul 2000  99.50302       100.97024       NA
Aug 2000  99.79381       101.09395       NA
Sep 2000 100.17704       102.56415       NA
Oct 2000 100.42983       103.80865       NA
```

**2) zoo**  This also works:

```
library(zoo)
FUN <- function(x) as.yearmon(x, "%YM%m")
tt <- as.ts(read.zoo(text = Lines, skip = 1, sep = ",", FUN = FUN))
```

To change the column names one can do this afterwards:

```
colnames(tt) <- c(...whatever...)
```

Comment: Thank you, solution 2) is a very elegant solution, seems to work very well.  What was causing me trouble was how to deal with the "M" placeholder in the middle but this solves!